# Is there a way to translate SQL that includes UNION + TOP + ORDER BY to Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I am new to ElasticSearch and I wondered whether there is a way to translate the following SQL to Elasticsearch DSL:

```
SELECT TOP 3 1 as Priority, * FROM Customers where ContactName like 'A%' 
UNION
SELECT TOP 3 2 as Priority, * FROM Customers where NOT(ContactName like 'A%')
ORDER BY Priority, ContactName ASC;
```

In addition, I would like to know whether there is an option to extend this query to something that is not supported by SQL... sort each of the queries in a different order (as far as I know cannot be done in SQL) so conceptually the SQL will looks like:

```
(SELECT TOP 3 1 as Priority, * FROM Customers where ContactName like 'A%'ORDER BY Priority, City ASC) 
UNION
(SELECT TOP 3 2 as Priority, * FROM Customers where NOT(ContactName like 'A%')
ORDER BY Priority, ContactName ASC);
```

Note: I prefer to get all the response objects as one response and not as list of responses that are associated with the specific source query (similar to response I'll get from the SQL statement above).

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do is to you two queries or [msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Alternative is to use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "cities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city-name.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "starts_with_A": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "customer-name.keyword",
            "include": "A.*",
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "starts_Not_with_A": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer-name.keyword",
        "exclude": "A.*",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks!
Indeed, msearch give me the proper results

Comment: Thanks @jaspreet,
1) How do I mark it as answered?
2) Is there any way to get all the answers as one list of objects (using boolean/should or other mechanism)?

Comment: @Shai should will not work as size and sort will be for whole query not individual blocks . You will have to combine at client side